# How to pass list of columns from one table to another table in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Following is my Table-A

```
Column_Name     Flag
-----------     ----
col-A             1
col-B             1
col-C             1
col-D             2
```

Columns col-A, col-B, col-C, col-D are present in Table-B as follows

```
ID col-A col-B col-C col-D
1    a    b      c     d
```

I want to write a query something like

```
select (select column_name from table-A where flag = 1) from table-B
```

Above query should translate to something like

```
select col-A, col-B, col-C from table-B.
```

I tried the following:

```
select Array_to_String(Array(select column_name from table-A where flag = 1)) from table-B
```

But the above function Array_to_string gives me the list of columns as a single string.

Comment: just to better understand your use-case  - what is the practical use of above?

Comment: I have a wide table with around 1000 columns and some of the columns are categorized in to some set of groups and every group of columns are identified with flag. So depending upon the group i have to choose certain set of columns.

Comment: but most likely just reducing projected columns is not the final goal, you might want to do something with them  - so what it is? is there any action like aggregation/etc. or some other logic to be actually apply on those selected columns?

Comment: btw, can you just simply create separate view for each group?

Comment: Yes you are correct. There is specific logic applied depending upon on the group of columns. For example if the group of columns are classified as continuous, we do aggregations like sum etc. For Binary columns with AND/OR.

Comment: Ok, so now your challenge looks more solvable than before :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is example for BigQuery Standard SQL

I've added yet another table (tableC) to have association between group)flag) and respective action. Overall it is simplified (as your question is) but shows possible approach - that you still will need to apply to your specific use case
Note, based on your comments - I assume you apply aggregation on columns within the rows

```
#standardSQL
WITH `tableA` AS (
  SELECT 'colA' Column_Name, 1 Flag UNION ALL
  SELECT 'colB', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'colC', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'colD', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'colE', 2 
), `tableB` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 1 colA, 2 colB, 3 colC, 4 colD, 5 colE UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 
), `tableC` AS (
  SELECT 1 flag, 'SUM' action UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'BIT_AND'
)
SELECT id, 
  CASE action 
    WHEN 'SUM' THEN SUM(CAST(val AS INT64))
    WHEN 'BIT_AND' THEN BIT_AND(CAST(val AS INT64)) 
  END val
FROM (
  SELECT id, 
    SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)] col,
    SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)] val
  FROM `tableB` t, 
  UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'^{|}$|"', ''))) kv
)
JOIN `tableA` ON col = Column_Name AND flag = 1 -- set flag here
JOIN `tableC` USING(flag)
GROUP BY id, action
```

You just need to set value for flag

If you set flag = 1 - result will be SUM of columns

```
Row id  val  
1   1   6    
2   2   18
```

If you set flag = 2 - result will be BIT_AND applied to "survived" columns

```
Row id  val  
1   1   4    
2   2   8
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mikhail for you solution. But still i don't see how is this intermediate step achieved. `select (select column_name from table-A where flag = 1) from table-B`. With you solution i think i need to do transpose to get my intermediate table.

Comment: Transpose of this table wil be the solution.`WITH `tableA` AS (
  SELECT 'colA' Column_Name, 1 Flag UNION ALL
  SELECT 'colB', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'colC', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'colD', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'colE', 2 
), `tableB` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 1 colA, 2 colB, 3 colC, 4 colD, 5 colE UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 
)
SELECT id, 
  col, val
FROM (
  SELECT id, 
    SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)] col,
    SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)] val
  FROM `tableB` t, 
  UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'^{|}$|"', ''))) kv
)
JOIN `tableA` ON col = Column_Name AND flag = 1;`

Comment: your original question / intermediate step is not achievable with just one query. that is why i asked you about your real output need and provided you an example of how to make it.